# RefreshControl only appearing on top of first child in a horizontal ScrollView (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, react-native, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I have a use case where I want to list horizontally cards.
I implemented it with a horizontal [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html).

Then, for each card I would like to implemented the pull-to-refresh pattern so that the data displayed in the card are updated.
I used therefore the [RefreshControl](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html) component as an attribute of the ScrollView.

The issue is that on iOS, when I switch to another card than the 1st, I cannot see the RefreshControl component (see gif below).

[image: horizontal scroll with refresh control iOS]

**Code**

```
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  directionalLockEnabled
  contentInset={{top: 1}}
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
      refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
      onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
    />
  }
>
  <Text style={styles.card}>First child</Text>
  <Text style={styles.card}>Second child</Text>
</ScrollView>
```

Full code in the demo below

**Demo** https://rnplay.org/apps/sRXpEw

**Edit**

It looks related to this part of the code : [Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L523-L529](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L523-L529)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is expected behavior of `refreshControl`- there is only supposed to be one.

Would this work for your app?

```
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  directionalLockEnabled
  contentInset={{top: 1}}
>
  <ScrollView
    refreshControl={
      <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
      />
    }><Text style={styles.card}>First child</Text></ScrollView>
  <ScrollView
    refreshControl={
      <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
      />
    }><Text style={styles.card}>Second child</Text></ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```